# Wake up GPS and Network locator before it's checked by an IntentService

Tags: android, geolocation, locationmanager

I've got a similar problem to the question asked here:
[Sending message to a Handler on a dead thread when getting a location from an IntentService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690198/sending-message-to-a-handler-on-a-dead-thread-when-getting-a-location-from-an-in)

I've put a LocationListener in an IntentService, which I hear is a bad place to put it since the listener gets destroyed after the `onHandleIntent()` completes.

My intent service checks the last known location based on GPS and Network provider. I'm looking for a way to "wake up" the GPS and Network locator before I check where the user is at.

The IntentService is run every minute, and it checks for an updated location every 5-30 minutes. Is there a way to setup a `requestLocationUpdates` that I can call prior to the actual location check?

```
12-31 14:09:33.664: W/MessageQueue(3264): Handler (android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1) {41403330} sending message to a      Handler on a dead thread
12-31 14:09:33.664: W/MessageQueue(3264): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1) {41403330} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-31 14:09:33.664: W/MessageQueue(3264): at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:196)
12-31 14:09:33.664: W/MessageQueue(3264): at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:473)
12-31 14:09:33.664: W/MessageQueue(3264): at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:446)
12-31 14:09:33.664: W/MessageQueue(3264): at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:383)
12-31 14:09:33.664: W/MessageQueue(3264): at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.onLocationChanged(LocationManager.java:193)
12-31 14:09:33.664: W/MessageQueue(3264): at android.location.ILocationListener$Stub.onTransact(ILocationListener.java:58)
12-31 14:09:33.664: W/MessageQueue(3264): at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
12-31 14:09:33.664: W/MessageQueue(3264): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

**ScheduledService**

```
public class ScheduledService extends IntentService {

    private LocationManager lm;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    public ScheduledService() {
        super("ScheduledService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                lm.removeUpdates(this);
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        };

        if(isNetworkAvailable()) {

            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

            try {
                Location lastKnownLocation = getBestLocation();
                double lat = lastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
                double lon = lastKnownLocation.getLongitude();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? If so could you answer your own question?

Comment: Yea sorry I usually make it a point to update my questions. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I'm not exactly sure but I believe I went with a different option and moved the  LocationListener out of the IntentService, because it gets destroyed after the onHandleIntent() completes.

I just realized I didn't know how to write this piece of code correctly so I went and looked for a library that did what I needed. Here's a starting point. I bookmarked it cause I found it useful: [Good way of getting the user's location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android)