# Warning - sending message to a Handler on a dead thread

Tags: android, warnings

the application is running fine but all of a sudden I getting these warnings. Even though my app is running fine now I think it might cause error in the future. Currently the code is kind of huge so I cannot upload it here. But I will tell you the features that I am using in my app.
1. Google Maps
2. GCM
3. Server related stuff - fetching json data etc etc

Can some one please tell me why it may be causing this error? below is the logcat warnings

```
06-23 10:55:04.814: W/MessageQueue(20267): Handler (android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler) {42943020} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-23 10:55:04.814: W/MessageQueue(20267): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler) {42943020} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-23 10:55:04.814: W/MessageQueue(20267):  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:320)
06-23 10:55:04.814: W/MessageQueue(20267):  at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
06-23 10:55:04.814: W/MessageQueue(20267):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:595)
06-23 10:55:04.814: W/MessageQueue(20267):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:566)
06-23 10:55:04.814: W/MessageQueue(20267):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:503)
06-23 10:55:04.814: W/MessageQueue(20267):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchScreenStateChange(ViewRootImpl.java:5995)
06-23 10:55:04.814: W/MessageQueue(20267):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$W.dispatchScreenState(ViewRootImpl.java:6339)
06-23 10:55:04.814: W/MessageQueue(20267):  at android.view.IWindow$Stub.onTransact(IWindow.java:140)
06-23 10:55:04.814: W/MessageQueue(20267):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
06-23 10:55:04.814: W/MessageQueue(20267):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Any help on this will be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending message to a Handler on a dead thread when getting a location from an IntentService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690198/sending-message-to-a-handler-on-a-dead-thread-when-getting-a-location-from-an-in)